# html5 video canceled

Tags: html5-video

I'm trying to embed a video on my website:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="new-slideshow.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

For some reason, the video is not loading, and I can see this information when I inspect the network request:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2241201/locker/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-14%20at%201.49.39%20PM.png

Why is the video being canceled?